# infinite sum of a series when the summand is squared and the non-squared series is known

Tags: sequences-and-series

Sum from 1 to infinity of f(x)^2 when the sum of f(x) from 1 to infinity is known. Is there a general technique for this?

I would like to try it myself without getting my particular problem solved.

Comment: I don't think there is a general formula.

Comment: There can be no such formula, compare $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^n}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(n+1)}$.